# Reference data from a range on one sheet to individual cells on another based on neighboring cell value (Excel 365)

Tags: excel

Sheet 1 will be references to individuals based on unique identifiers, such that column A will be their name and column B will have the identifier.

Sheet 2 will be an imported list of all individuals in our data set, such that column A is their name and column B is the identifier.

The goal is to be able to fill cells in Sheet 1 Column A based off of values entered in Sheet 1 Column B, by referring to Sheet 2 Column B., i.e. if the column B values match between sheets, I want the neighboring value in Column A to be copied over.

I'm a novice at this, but I don't think CONCATENATE is what I'm looking for, so the closest I've gotten is:

```
=IF($B:$B=Sheet2!$B:$B,Sheet2!$A:$A)
```

which results in a SPILL error, because I think my formula is trying to display multiple reference cells of data in one destination cell, whereas a formula such as

```
=IF(B3=Sheet2!B3, Sheet2!A3)
```

returns expected results, but is too limited for my purposes, in that it would be potentially faster to just manually enter the data, at that rate.

Trying to simplify, I'll have a sheet that has say 100 people in it, with identifiers 1 through 100. If I punch in their identifier in a separate sheet, I'm looking for their name to be displayed in a neighboring cell, or at least to have their name returned in the same cell, i.e. I enter "90" in Sheet1A1 or Sheet1B1 and it gives me "John Doe" in A1, which is the value of Sheet2B90 that's associated with the number "90" that is in Sheet2A90.

Comment: If you can rearrange the columns on Sheet2 with the ID in the first column and the name in the second column, you could use `VLOOKUP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So VLOOKUP does work with some wrangling, but XLOOKUP was the ultimate solution to what I needed. A formula such as

```
=XLOOKUP(A13,$A$1:$A$10,$B$1:$C$10,NONE)
```

Would return data from B1 through B10 and C1 through C10 to elsewhere in the sheet, in this case next to a lookup cell A13 into cells B13 and C13, if the value in A13 appears within the lookup array of A1 through A10. Locking the cells with $ allows the formula to be dragged down a range of lookup cells without Excel incrementing the values of the lookup or return arrays, just the value of the lookup cell.